# How do I run TravisCI on stage when I push to any branch?

Tags: heroku, travis-ci

Here is my `travis.yml`.  I am trying to figure out how to run when I push to any branch.  Under `app`, I am forced to put the specific branch that I am working on.  I want to use `all_branches: true`. If I use `all_branche: true`, then what is the `key` under `app`?  I want to use a generic word like `stage`, but I am thinking that it looking for a specific branch name, because when I tried `stage`, I got a `404`.  Also, does the `app` `key`, in this case `feature/travisCi` have to match the `branch`?  The docs aren't very clear, so I am looking for a bit deeper explanation.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- node
- '6'
before_deploy:
- npm run build
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: ... secret key
  app: 
    feature/travisCi: morning-engine-36163
  on:
    repo: hipshot/dashboardfe
    branch: feature/travisCi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch specification for the `app` key is only required if you'd like to deploy each of your branches to a different application in Heroku.

For example, if you have a `master` branch which you want to deploy to your production Heroku app, and you have a `staging` branch which is the one you might like to deploy to your staging Heroku app, then you can do as follows:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- node
- '6'
before_deploy:
- npm run build
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: ... secret key
  app: 
    master: heroku_app_name_for_production
    staging: heroku_app_name_for_staging
  on:
    all_branches: true
```

However, if you only have a Heroku app and you want to deploy there any changes in any of your branches, it's not needed to specify the `branch: heroku_app` section under `app`, and you can simply use:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- node
- '6'
before_deploy:
- npm run build
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: ... secret key
  app: your_heroku_app_name
  on:
    all_branches: true
```

Another typical scenario would be to only deploy to Heroku the changes to your `master` branch. To do so:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- node
- '6'
before_deploy:
- npm run build
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: ... secret key
  app: your_heroku_app_name
  on:
    branch: master
```

Getting back to your specific example, if you're going to restrict the deploy to your `feature/travisCi` branch, this should work:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- node
- '6'
before_deploy:
- npm run build
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: ... secret key
  app: morning-engine-36163
  on:
    branch: feature/travisCi
```